# Controller that returns JSON format not returning to target page

Tags: model-view-controller, jsonresult

1. Why is it that my controller can't manage to go to the target Index page after logging in?

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public JsonResult Login(FormCollection fc)
   {
       var isSuccess = false;
       Array errors = null;

       more code here...

       return Json(new { infoMessage = errors, successMessage = "", Status = isSuccess, gotoUrl = string.Format("/MyAccounts/Index") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```

The motive is to redirect the page to Index but it returns the Json result document instead.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add return inside if statement

```
if(isSuccess == true) {
  //return redirect to target page
}
else {
  return Json(new { infoMessage = errors, successMessage = "", Status = isSuccess, gotoUrl = string.Format("/MyAccounts/Index") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't go to any target page because you specified it to return a `json`. What you want is to redirect to an action.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "MyAccounts");
```